# Is there an abbreviation for gunner? (American football positions)

Tags: american-football, position

It seems there is no abbreviation for gunner among American football positions.
G is used for offensive guards, so it is ineligible.

Comment: *"Gunner"* is not a position, it is a playing tactical style. Of course no abbreviation exists in the same level as TE, WR, QB, for example.